# Atom continually freezing on styles.less

Tags: atom-editor

I was playing around with the CSS in the Atom editor the other day, open it back up today and this is what I see.. Every time I try to close any of those 3 tabs it freezes up, I've even rebooted my computer to no avail.

[image]

Comment: I have removed Atom and reinstalled. Didn't change a thing.......

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking "Open Empty Editor On Start" and you know.. that worked for some reason.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens, but I have encountered similar problem that was caused by tabs opened last time.

Usually, I solve the problem by opening with "Clear window state". The command (I see that you are using ubuntu?):

```
atom --clear-window-state
```

[Reference](http://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/debugging/#clearing-saved-state)